# How to I change my data structure so that I can run an ANOVA on it?

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I have a dataframe containing columns representing taxonomic phyla with rows representing individual samples, each element in the dataframe is a simpsons Index of diversity, I shall include a screenshot of the dataframe for reference.

I am trying to run an ANOVA/KRUSKALL wallis test comparing one of the phyla columns simpsons index values to all of the others, to determine if it's simpsons index is significantly different to the other phyla.

When I find guides on how to run these statistical tests in R, it seems to be working with a completely different data structure to what I am working with , where columns would represent sample number, phyla and then simpsons index.

I assume I need to change the data structure? Because honestly I have no idea how else I'm going to run these statistical tests.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rmwv.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! To show you how to reformat your data, we are going to need access to it.  By posting your data as an image, you are forcing us to type your data in by hand before we start answering your question.  I for one am not prepared to do that when you have easier options available to you.  Please add the output from `dput(<your data>)` to your question.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help you create a *minimal working example*.

Comment: How do I add that output to my question?

Comment: Run `dput(<your data object here>)` at the console.  Copy-and-paste the output into your question.  The link I gave you provides more information and context.